# Automate file save in microsoft edge using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge-chromium

I am using the beta version of selenium webdriver(4.0.0) for microsoft edge. I can't figure out how to save the data as pdf that is in print window, which opens after I click on a button in main window

```
           var found = await driver.WaitForElementToAppear(".//font[contains(text(),'Uploaded')]", 180, token);
            if(found)
            {
//All buttons , which when clicked opens Print window
                var ebrcElements = driver.ElementsByXpath(".//input[@type='submit']");
                foreach (var ebrcElement in ebrcElements)
                {
                    ebrcElement.Click();//Opens the new window
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    driver.SwitchToNewWindow();//Switches to the last window
//The window has "Print" and "Cancel" button
                    driver.CloseCurrentWindow();
                    driver.SwitchToFirstWindow();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the window that opens when print button is clicked, is an os dialog box, it cannot be accessed directly from selenium. The way I solved the problem was using P/Invoke.
Using visual studio's spy++ tool it was easy to find the window handle and its caption.

Next I defined method

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
```

and Called it like,

```
       var saveHandle = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Save Print Output As");
```

Next step was to bring the window to foreground using the handle. For that I used the method

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Last step was to simulate the keyboard and mouse operations. For that I used library InputSimulator. It can be downloaded using nuget package manager

```
                var ins = new InputSimulator();
                ins.Keyboard.TextEntry($"ebrc{irandom.NextDouble()}");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                ins.Keyboard.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
                ins.Keyboard.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
                ins.Keyboard.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
```